# eclipse/egit: unable to add ONLY subfolder to git

Tags: eclipse, egit

I wanted to add an external dir (tracked in git), to my eclipse project. This dir contains source code for my project. I know how to add an external source and attempted that.

I observe that eclipse project is not showing that external dir as git repository. Is there a way it can be resolved.

Regards,
AV

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse IDE connects "projects" to SCM, not individual folder. What you can do, assuming you are using Neon release, is to also import this directory as project with `File > Import project from filesystem...`. Then if having it both as a project and a folder in your IDE is an issue, you can use Project Explorer and set its "Project layout" to hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I resolved my issue.

I created a new java project. File > New Java Project, but I did not select the default (workspace location) for the project dir. I pointed that to my source folder. 
As a result of that, my src dir is now part of a eclipse project, and is visible as git repo in eclipse ide.
I also added a .gitingore file to only checkin src folder i.e. exclude any other folder than src